# How to ensure that a string contains numbers and letters by using RegEx

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match strings that either:

- Contains between 9 and 15 numbers (Only numbers)
- Contains between 6 and 15 numbers+letters (it must contain both, numbers and letters. Only letters is not a valid option).

I have the following regex: `\b([0-9]{9,15})|([A-Za-z0-9]{6,15})\b` which fails because the second part allows you to have a string with 6 numbers or 6 letters only.

Should be valid:

- 123456789
- 12345678Y
- Y234Y2

Should not be valid:

- 12345678
- 123X4
- ABCDEFGHYJ

Comment: `\b([0-9]{9,15}|[A-Za-z0-9]{6,15})\b`. It should be `\b(a|b)\b`, not `\b(a)|(b)\b`

Comment: That would not work @WiktorStribiżew, because 12345678 is TRUE and it should be FALSE. The string must either be minimum 9 chars length if it only contain numbers, or min 6 char length if it contains characters

Comment: `^(?:[0-9]{9,15}|(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[a-zA-Z])[A-Za-z0-9]{6,15})$`? https://regex101.com/r/b4e5n0/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:[0-9]{9,15}|(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[a-zA-Z])[A-Za-z0-9]{6,15})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b4e5n0/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:`  - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[0-9]{9,15}` -  nine to 15 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[a-zA-Z])[A-Za-z0-9]{6,15}` - six to 15 alphanumeric chars with at least one digit and at least one letter
- `)` - end of the group
- `$`  - end of string.